# Adding existing attribute to all attribute sets

Tags: magento

I have an **existing** attribute for an embed code. I need to associate this attribute with 120+ existing attribute sets.

If I know the attribute set id, how can I go about adding the attribute to all attribute sets programmatically?

Comment: do you have common attribute set group ( like general / meta / etc,, ) that you want to add the attribute in ?

Comment: @Meabed We do, however all products are assigned to specific (and different) attribute sets. However all attribute sets need to have this specific attribute. So I have to find a way to mass update.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have found it interesting to write code for this issue so here is the solution that works :)

Run this code in php script including mage.php and let me know if it works well.

> replace ( firstname ) with the attribute code that you want to mass add to all attribute sets

```
    $attSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_code','catalog_product')->getFirstItem(); // This is because the you adding the attribute to catalog_products entity ( there is different entities in magento ex : catalog_category, order,invoice... etc ) 
    $attSetCollection = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->load($attSet->getId())->getAttributeSetCollection(); // this is the attribute sets associated with this entity 
    $attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
        ->setCodeFilter('firstname')
        ->getFirstItem();
    $attCode = $attributeInfo->getAttributeCode();
    $attId = $attributeInfo->getId();
    foreach ($attSetCollection as $a)
    {
        $set = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($a->getId());
        $setId = $set->getId();
        $group = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id',$setId)->setOrder('attribute_group_id',"ASC")->getFirstItem();
        $groupId = $group->getId();
        $newItem = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
        $newItem->setEntityTypeId($attSet->getId()) // catalog_product eav_entity_type id ( usually 10 )
                  ->setAttributeSetId($setId) // Attribute Set ID
                  ->setAttributeGroupId($groupId) // Attribute Group ID ( usually general or whatever based on the query i automate to get the first attribute group in each attribute set )
                  ->setAttributeId($attId) // Attribute ID that need to be added manually
                  ->setSortOrder(10) // Sort Order for the attribute in the tab form edit
                  ->save()
        ;
        echo "Attribute ".$attCode." Added to Attribute Set ".$set->getAttributeSetName()." in Attribute Group ".$group->getAttributeGroupName()."<br>\n";
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, however I'm hoping (wondering) if there is a way to set the position. Ideally, I'd like it as the last item of the General section. Is this possible? Screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/0O0H0x0E2h05. Thanks so much!

Comment: change position in the tab ->setSortOrder(10) // change this 10 to higher number !

Comment: The higher number will set the sort order, so I can ensure that it's at the bottom. However there's no clear way to select the General group. Right now it looks like you're using ->getFirstItem(), which would require that the General group always be the first. Is there a way to only select the General group? Thanks again!

Comment: Simple fix. `->addFieldToFilter('attribute_group_name', 'General')` when calling `eav/entity_attribute_group`.

Comment: yes you could select only general group gut i made the code so it works for every one ( so i wasn't sure that you have general group in all the attribute sets ) so i have done it get the first item ( means first group ) in each attribute set so this will working with all people :)

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me on Magento EE 1.11.1.0. I did have to wrap the 'ASC' argument in quotes, as it was triggering an E_NOTICE.

Comment: For novice coders that need this add the following lines before the code `require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();`

Answer (score 2):

for people having problems with the code above,

like: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object

you need to add the following to to top of your file:

```
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
```

edit:

im using magento 1.8.1.0 and the code still didn't work

i had to add the following line to $newItem, this way the validation passes

```
    ->setAttributeCode($attCode)
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup::addAttribute()` can be used to update as well as add attributes.  Another thing I find useful is if you specify a group with this function it is automatically assigned to all sets.

```
$attributeCode = 'name'; // choose your attribute here
$setup = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/setup');
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode, array(
    // no need to specify fields already used like 'label' or 'type'
    'group'      => 'General',
    'sort_order' => 10
));
```

Comment: When trying this method on 1.9.3.1, I get "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function select() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php on line 733"

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a external script (not the magento setups script) this work form me

```
<?php
/// run in magento root
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
Mage::app();

$attributeCode = 'my_attr_code';
$group = 'MyGroup';
$sortOrder = 10;

//this way you config the setup connections
$setup = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup('catalog_setup');

$setup->startSetup();
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode, array(
    'group'      => $group,
    'sort_order' => $sortOrder
));
```

(as answer to @Eric)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/setup');
```

But use

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$attributeSets = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
    ->setEntityTypeFilter('4'); // Catalog Product Entity Type ID
foreach ($attributeSets as $attributeSet) {
    $installer->addAttributeToSet(
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,   // Entity type
        $attributeSet->getAttributeSetName(), // Attribute set name
        'General',                            // Attribute set group name
        $yourAttributeCode,
        100                                   // Position on the attribute set group
    );
}
```